# Send flow table entries from POX Controller to switch without the switch initiating conversation

Tags: networking, sdn, openflow, pox

I want to send flow table entries asynchronously from POX controller to an OpenFlow switch without the switch initiating the conversation. Is it possible?

The use case here is that I'm simulating a firewall using the OpenFlow switch and want to dynamically block an IP and this message should come from the controller without the switch starting the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

During the ConnectionUp event,
you can install any flow rules that you like for each switch as soon as it is connected to the controller.
If you are asking arbitrary installing rules, then during the ConnectionUp event you can save the connection with the switch and later send the flow rules to the switch.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Can you suggest any tutorial for the same?